# A webpage has a “waffle blocking layer” in Firefox and blocks to see the content behind screen. It works fine on IE

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer

Boa tarde.

Estou tentando acessar uma página desenvolvida e usada internamente pela empresa em um navegador diferente do IE e não tenho conseguido. 
A página parece que executa um script java que cria um bloco que bloqueia o conteúdo ao usar outros navegadores diferentes do internet explorer.

Quando desativo o java script, ele carrega com sucesso a primeira página de login... mas não consigo dar continuidade na navegação.

Olhando um pouco mais, verifiquei que o código HTML parece colocar uma "waffle blocking layer", que cria um quadrado na tela e bloqueia o conteúdo.

Definindo o valor para "0" manualmente, consigo executá-lo Anexei a imagem a este tópico.

[image: Blocking Layer]

[image: Grey Square Block]

Alguém sabe o que poderia estar causando esse bloqueio? E como eu poderia acessar normalmente de outros navegadores?

Obrigado!